# How to transform a dataframe for getting time of various occurence of events?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given the following DataFrame:

```
+-------+-----+-------+-----+--------+---------------------------+
|  DID  | CID | Event | OID | Source |         TimeStamp         |
+-------+-----+-------+-----+--------+---------------------------+
| 25078 |  14 | QBT   |   0 | EMS    | 2019-10-15 10:54:35 +0000 |
| 25078 |  14 | NDOBT |   0 | EMS    | 2019-10-15 10:54:48 +0000 |
| 25078 |  14 | SBT   |   0 | EMS    | 2019-10-15 10:54:52 +0000 |
| 25078 |  14 | SBT-1 |   0 | ECS    | 2019-10-15 11:00:01 +0000 |
| 25078 |  14 | SBT-1 |   0 | ECS    | 2019-10-15 11:00:26 +0000 |
| 25078 |  14 | SBT-1 |   0 | ECS    | 2019-10-15 11:00:50 +0000 |
| 25078 |  14 | SBT   |   0 | EMS    | 2019-10-15T14:27:45       |
| 25078 |  14 | SBT   |   0 | EMS    | 2019-10-15T14:27:45       |
| 25078 |  14 | LSFA  |   0 | SPDLS  | 2019-10-15T14:28:16       |
| 25078 |  14 | LSFA  |   0 | SPDLS  | 2019-10-15T14:28:16       |
| 25078 |  14 | FEAR  |   0 | CBS    | 2019-10-15T14:28:18       |
| 25078 |  14 | FEAR  |   0 | CBS    | 2019-10-15T14:28:18       |
| 25078 |  14 | SBT   |   0 | EMS    | 2019-10-15T14:28:44       |
| 25078 |  14 | SBT   |   0 | EMS    | 2019-10-15T14:28:44       |
| 25078 |  14 | LSFA  |   0 | SPDLS  | 2019-10-15T14:30:55       |
| 25078 |  14 | LSFA  |   0 | SPDLS  | 2019-10-15T14:30:55       |
| 25078 |  14 | SBT   |   0 | EMS-1  | 2019-10-15T15:28:43       |
| 25078 |  14 | SBT   |   0 | EMS-1  | 2019-10-15T15:29:02       |
| 25078 |  14 | FEAR  |   0 | CBS    | 2019-10-15T15:30:51       |
| 25078 |  14 | FEAR  |   0 | CBS    | 2019-10-15T15:30:51       |
| 25078 |  14 | DBT   |   0 | RS     | 2019-10-15T15:44:23       |
| 25078 |  14 | QBT   |   0 | EMS-1  | 2019-10-15T16:02:16       |
+-------+-----+-------+-----+--------+---------------------------+
```

I want to get the first and last occurrences of some events and source so that the final output looks something like this:

```
+-------+-----+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
|  DID  | CID |  Event-QBT-Last-DT  | Event-QBT-First-DT |  Event-SBT-Last-DT  | Event-SBT-First-DT |    Screen-ECS-First-DT    |    Screen-ECS-Last-DT     |      FirstTimeUsage       |   LastTime Usage    |
+-------+-----+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
| 25078 |  14 | 2019-10-15T16:02:16 | 10/15/19 10:54 AM  | 2019-10-15T15:29:02 | 10/15/19 10:54 AM  | 2019-10-15 11:00:01 +0000 | 2019-10-15 11:00:50 +0000 | 2019-10-15 10:54:35 +0000 | 2019-10-15T16:02:16 |
+-------+-----+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
```

How can i achieve this using pandas.

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is filtering rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for get first and last occurrences of some events, then use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `first` and `last`  and reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), last flatten `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
L = ['QBT','SBT']

df1 = (df[df['Event'].isin(L)]
         .groupby(['OID','DID','CID','Event'])['TimeStamp']
         .agg([('Last-DT','last'), ('First-DT','first')])
         .unstack()
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df1.columns = [f'Event-{b}-{a}' for a, b in df1.columns]
#print (df1)
```

For first and last occurence use first solution with no filter, no `Event` in groupby and no `unstack`:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['OID','DID','CID'])['TimeStamp']
         .agg([('FirstTimeUsage','first'), ('LastTime Usage','last')]))
#print (df2)
```

Last join by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) together:

```
df = df1.join(df2).reset_index()
print (df)
   OID    DID  CID         Event-QBT-First-DT    Event-QBT-Last-DT  \
0    0  25078   14  2019-10-15 10:54:35 +0000  2019-10-15T16:02:16   

          Event-SBT-First-DT    Event-SBT-Last-DT             FirstTimeUsage  \
0  2019-10-15 10:54:52 +0000  2019-10-15T15:29:02  2019-10-15 10:54:35 +0000   

        LastTime Usage  
0  2019-10-15T16:02:16
```

EDIT: For processing next column a bit modify generate `df1`:

```
L = ['QBT','SBT']

df1 = (df[df['Event'].isin(L)]
         .groupby(['OID','DID','CID','Event'])['TimeStamp']
         .agg([('Last-DT','last'), ('First-DT','first')])
         .unstack()
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df1.columns = [f'Event-{b}-{a}' for a, b in df1.columns]
#print (df1)

L2 = ['ECS']
df11 = (df[df['Source'].isin(L2)]
         .groupby(['OID','DID','CID','Source'])['TimeStamp']
         .agg([('Last-DT','last'), ('First-DT','first')])
         .unstack()
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df11.columns = [f'Screen-{b}-{a}' for a, b in df11.columns]

df2 = (df.groupby(['OID','DID','CID'])['TimeStamp']
         .agg([('FirstTimeUsage','first'), ('LastTime Usage','last')]))
```

An d last use `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df11, df2], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   OID    DID  CID         Event-QBT-First-DT    Event-QBT-Last-DT  \
0    0  25078   14  2019-10-15 10:54:35 +0000  2019-10-15T16:02:16   

          Event-SBT-First-DT    Event-SBT-Last-DT        Screen-ECS-First-DT  \
0  2019-10-15 10:54:52 +0000  2019-10-15T15:29:02  2019-10-15 11:00:01 +0000   

          Screen-ECS-Last-DT             FirstTimeUsage       LastTime Usage  
0  2019-10-15 11:00:50 +0000  2019-10-15 10:54:35 +0000  2019-10-15T16:02:16
```

Comment: thank for the answer but i made an edit to  my question i also want find an entry from `Screen` column

Comment: Hi @jezrael, quick off-topic question. Any idea how to flatten multi-index into a single index as part of a method chain? I have not been able to find a solution other than `df.columns = `

Comment: @MarkWang - hmmm, Understand, what need, but seems not exist yet.

Comment: In my head, it should be something like `df.set_axis` with a callable, like `assign`

Comment: hi, @jezrael can this problem be solve using loc or iloc or some form of selection method. Or groupby is the only suitable option

Comment: @M_S_N - What problem?

Comment: @jezrael the same problem/ question posted by tsu90280 which you have answered.

Comment: @M_S_N I got it, need groupby, because working per groups.

Comment: @jezrael ok, understood

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a function and use `apply` to run over DataFrame like this:

```
def f(x):
    first_used_DT=x.min()['TimeStamp']
    last_used_DT=x.max()['TimeStamp']
    first_ECS=x[x['Source']=='ECS'].min()['TimeStamp']
    last_ECS=x[x['Source']=='ECS'].max()['TimeStamp']
    last_OBT=x[x['Event']=='QBT'].max()['TimeStamp']
    first_QBT=x[x['Event']=='QBT'].min()['TimeStamp']
    last_SBT=x[x['Event']=='SBT'].max()['TimeStamp']
    first_SBT=x[x['Event']=='SBT'].min()['TimeStamp']

    return pd.DataFrame({'FirstTimeUsage': first_used_DT, 'LastTime Usage': last_used_DT,
                         'Screen-ECS-First-DT':first_ECS,'Screen-ECS-Last-DT':last_ECS
                        'Event-QBT-First-DT':first_QBT, 'Event-QBT-Last-DT':last_OBT,
                         'Event-SBT-First-DT':first_SBT, 'Event-SBT-Last-DT':last_SBT
                         }, index=[0])
```

```
df.groupby(['DID', 'OID', 'CID']).apply(f).reset_index(0)
```

Maybe a little slower but gets the job done.

Comment: this solution was actually inspired from @jezrael other post on SO.